# How to draw a path to form a regular pentagon?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, nodes, paths, polygon

I already have a code that draws a regular hexagon the following way

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,shape=circle,fill=blue}]
\path (0,0) node (p0) {}
(-1.5,-1) node (p1) {}
(-1.5,-2.5) node (p2) {}
(1.5,-2.5) node (p3) {}
(1.5,-1) node (p4) {}
(0,-3.5) node (p5) { };
\draw (p0) -- (p1)
(p0) -- (p1)
(p0) -- (p2)
(p0) -- (p3)
(p0) -- (p4)
(p0) -- (p5)
(p1) -- (p2)
(p1) -- (p3)
(p1) -- (p4)
(p1) -- (p5)
(p2) -- (p3)
(p2) -- (p4)
(p2) -- (p5)
(p3) -- (p4)
(p3) -- (p5)
(p4) -- (p5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But Now I need to remove one of the points and to draw a regular pentagon the same way. So I need to remove (P5) and to recalibrate all other points (change their coordinates) But I don't need to change the code much.

Is there a way to do it by just slightly changing my code here. ?

Comment: Define your points using the polar notation for radius+angle of rotation. Then you can simply make the angle 360 / number of sides, and your code is completely general...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the geometric shapes given by the shapes.geometric library

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mystyle/.style={draw,shape=circle,fill=blue}]
\def\ngon{5}
\node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\ngon,minimum size=3cm] (p) {};
\foreach\x in {1,...,\ngon}{\node[mystyle] (p\x) at (p.corner \x){};}
\foreach\x in {1,...,\numexpr\ngon-1\relax}{
  \foreach\y in {\x,...,\ngon}{
    \draw (p\x) -- (p\y);
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

For ngon being 9

[image]

Answer (score 12):

One short tikz code without use of a library.

```
\documentclass[border=7mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {3,...,7}
  \tikz\foreach \i in {1,...,\n}
    \fill (\i*360/\n:1) coordinate (n\i) circle(2 pt)
      \ifnum \i>1 foreach \j in {\i,...,1}{(n\i) edge (n\j)} \fi;
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: surely you meant `\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}`, then your answer could be even shorter :)

Comment: @MarkWibrow yes, but the problem with `[tikz]` is that in this case `standalone` produce one page and so one image for every `\tikz` :(

Comment: ah yes. rather silly of me not to notice that.

Answer (score 8):

For fun, a short code with `pst-poly`  gets the desired result:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-poly}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=3.5cm, dimen=middle, linejoin=1, dotsize=12pt}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(1,1)
    \providecommand{\PstPolygonNode}{\psdots[dotsize=12pt, linecolor=SteelBlue](1;\INode)
    }
    \rput(0,0){\PstPentagon[PolyName=A, linecolor=LightSteelBlue, linewidth=1.2pt] }
    \rput(0,0){\PstPentagon[PolyName=A, PolyOffset=2] }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you like the following (based on (Thruston comment) rude solution (still need some manual calculation):

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,shape=circle,fill=blue,text=white}]
    \foreach \i [count=\ii from 0] in {90,150,...,390}
\path (\i:32mm) node (p\ii) {\ii};
    \foreach \x in {0,...,5}
        \foreach \y in {\x,...,5}
\draw (p\y) -- (p\x);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For change number of nodes you need to determine start angle and manually determine next and final angle of node position.

[image]

Number in nodes are only informative, you can erase it.

**Upgrade:** An improved version, which itself calculate all necessary data from given number of nodes and angle of the first node position:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 every node/.style={draw,shape=circle,fill=blue,text=white}]
%%%% variable data data
\def\numpoly{8}%number of nodes
\def\startangle{30}%direction of the first node
\def\pradious{33mm}
%------- calculations of the positions angles
\pgfmathparse{int(\startangle+360/\numpoly)}%
    \let\nextangle=\pgfmathresult
\pgfmathparse{int(\startangle-360/\numpoly+360)}%
    \let\endtangle=\pgfmathresult
%--- nodes
    \foreach \i [count=\ii from 1] in {\startangle,\nextangle,...,\endtangle}
\path (\i:\pradious) node (p\ii) {\ii};
%--- interconnections
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\numpoly}
        \foreach \y in {\x,...,\numpoly}
\draw (p\y) -- (p\x);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With selection node numbers = 8 and the first node as in direction 30 degrees, code we obtain:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is a version in [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it) for comparison.  Something of an exercise in loops.

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";
vardef polygon(expr n) = for t=0 step 360/n until 359: right rotated t -- endfor cycle enddef;
beginfig(1);
path p; 
for n=3 upto 7:
  p := polygon(n) scaled 20 shifted (n*48,0);
  for i=1 upto length p:
    for j=i+1 upto length p:
      draw point i of p -- point j of p;
    endfor
  endfor
  for i=1 upto length p:
    fill fullcircle scaled 3 shifted point i of p withcolor .67 red;
  endfor
endfor
endfig;
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

With the PGF graph drawing stuff (compile with `lualatex`):

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}
\tikzgraphsset{declare={polygon_n}{[clique]\foreach\x in\tikzgraphV{\x/}}}
\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {3,...,7}
  \tikz\graph [clockwise, nodes={circle, fill=blue, inner sep=1}] 
    { polygon_n [n=\n] };
\end{document}
```

[image]