# How to make bigger loops?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, luatex, graphs

I have this code, adapted from the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330112/how-to-generalize-this-graph):

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard,graphdrawing,arrows.meta,quotes}
\usegdlibrary{circular}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{countme}
\setcounter{countme}{0}
\newcommand*\countup{\stepcounter{countme}\thecountme}
\newcommand*\countset{\setcounter{countme}{0}}
\tikzset{%
  edge counter/.style={"\countup"},
}
\tikz[>=Stealth]{%
  \graph [simple necklace layout, grow=left, node sep=20mm, nodes={circle},  edge quotes center, edge quotes={fill=white, inner sep=1pt, font=\scriptsize}]
  {
    subgraph C_n [n=2, -!-];
    { [edges={edge counter}]
      1->2->[loop left] 2 ;
    }
  };
}
\end{document}
```

It makes this graph:

### [image: Heading]

I am interested in making the loop larger. The manual I have (http://pgf.sourceforge.net/pgf_CVS.pdf) on p. 739, talks about the loop key as part of the `topaths` library. But the options are quite limited, and there seems to be nothing about sizing.

I don't need to use the loop key and am open to anything that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in section 70.3 of the tikz/PGF 3.0.1a manual you will find some other options including `distance`. Adding `distance=2cm` produces:

[image]

You can also use `looseness` and the various bend to control the loop.

For completeness, here's the full code but I only only added the distance command:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard,graphdrawing,arrows.meta,quotes}
\usegdlibrary{circular}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{countme}
\setcounter{countme}{0}
\newcommand*\countup{\stepcounter{countme}\thecountme}
\newcommand*\countset{\setcounter{countme}{0}}
\tikzset{%
  edge counter/.style={"\countup"},
}
\tikz[>=Stealth]{%
  \graph [simple necklace layout, grow=left, node sep=20mm, nodes={circle},  edge quotes center, edge quotes={fill=white, inner sep=1pt, font=\scriptsize}]
  {
    subgraph C_n [n=2, -!-];
    { [edges={edge counter}]
      1->2->[loop left,distance=2cm] 2 ;
    }
  };
}
\end{document}
```