# TikZ: Polygon shape with lines connecting all edges which are numbered

Tags: tikz-pgf

I took the following picture [image: photograph]

I want to recreate the same exact graph in the same style. Does anyone know how to do this with TikZ?

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: Welcome! My first comment is just a so-called boilerplate text (standard text) taken from https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4267/

Comment: On the site are plenty of similar images ... search for them, Also look to http://www.texample.net/ ...

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281031/how-to-draw-a-path-to-form-a-regular-pentagon/281038#281038.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a Ti*k*Z solution, using

1. The number of nodes as a constant, defined with `\newcommand`. This makes sure that you don't overwrite any existing command.
2. Polar coordinates of the form `(angle:radius)`, so we can do a for loop over all desired angles in order to create a nice circle.
3. `\pgfsetmacro` to do a calculation and save the result in a variable (e.g. `\angle`)
4. PGF's `ifthenelse` to handle the first and last value (1 and 8 in this case)
5. Again, PGF's `ifthenelse` to check for connections we don't have to draw, i.e. diagonal connections, and the connections to the next and previous node.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\newcommand{\numnodes}{8}

\foreach \ii in {1, ..., \numnodes}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{90 - (\ii-1)*360/\numnodes}
    \node[circle, draw, fill=blue!40] (x\ii) at (\angle:2cm) {\ii};
}

\foreach \ii in {1, ..., \numnodes}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\prev}{int(ifthenelse(\ii==1, \numnodes, \ii-1))}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\next}{int(ifthenelse(\ii==\numnodes, 1, \ii+1))}
    \draw (x\ii) -- (0,0) (x\prev) -- (x\ii) -- (x\next);

    \foreach \jj in {\ii, ..., \numnodes}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\drawoptions}{ifthenelse(
            \jj==(\ii+\numnodes/2) || \jj==\prev || \jj==\next,
            "none", "gray")}
        \path[draw=\drawoptions, thin, dashed] (x\ii) -- (x\jj);
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution with `pstricks` (and `auto-pst-pdf` to compile with `pdflatex`):

```
\documentclass[border=3pt, svgnames]{standalone}%

\usepackage{pgffor, etoolbox}
\usepackage{pst-poly, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\everypsbox{\footnotesize}
\begin{pspicture}
    \providecommand{\PstPolygonNode}{%
        \rput{*0}(1;\INode){\circlenode[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=LightSteelBlue!60, linecolor=LightSteelBlue, framesep=1pt]{C\the\multidocount}{\the\multidocount}}}
    \psset{ linewidth=0.6pt}
    \rput{67.5}(0,0){\PstOctogon[unit=2, PolyRotation=90]}
    \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5,6}{\foreach \y in {3,4,5,6,7,8}{\ifnumequal{\x}{\y}{\relax}{\ifnumequal{\y-\x}{4}{\ncline{C\x}{C\y}}{\psset{linestyle=dashed, dash=3pt 3pt, linewidth=0.6pt, linecolor=LightSteelBlue}\ncline{C\x}{C\y}}}}}
    \rput{67.5}(0,0){\PstOctogon[unit=2, PolyRotation=90]}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just slightly adopted my answer in the link ([how-to-draw-a-path-to-form-a-regular-pentagon](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281031/%E2%80%A6.)) given in my the comment below question:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style={draw=blue,shape=circle,fill=blue!50,inner sep=1pt,
                   minimum size=5mm,font=\small, text=white}
                        ]
%%%% variable data data
\def\numpoly{8}%number of nodes
\def\startangle{90}%angle of the first node
\def\pradious{22mm}
%------- calculations positions angles
\pgfmathparse{int(\startangle+360/\numpoly)}%
    \let\nextangle=\pgfmathresult
\pgfmathparse{int(\startangle-360/\numpoly+360)}%
    \let\endangle=\pgfmathresult
%--- regular polygon nodes
    \foreach \i [count=\ii from 1] in {\startangle,\nextangle,...,\endangle}
{
\path (\i:\pradious) node (p\ii) {\ii};
}
%--- nodes interconnections
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\numpoly}
        \foreach \y in {\x,...,\numpoly}
\draw[dashed,blue] (p\y) -- (p\x);

    \foreach \i [count=\ii] in {2,...,\numpoly, 1}
\draw[semithick, red] (p\ii) -- (p\i);

    \foreach \i [count=\ii] in {2,...,\numpoly, 1}
{    
\draw[semithick, red] (p\ii) -- (p\i);
\draw[semithick, red] (0,0) -- (p\ii);
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```