# Drawing a graph with a Loop and Mod function in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'm trying to draw a digraph on seven vertices, where each vertex `i` is connected to vertex `i+1`, `i+2` and `i+4` (mod 8). This is the code I wrote:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick, scale=1]
        % Nodes     
        \draw \foreach \x in {1,...,7}{
            (51.42*\x + 38.58:2.5) node(\x){\footnotesize\textsf \x}
        };

        % Edges
        \foreach \x in {1,...,7}
        \path[line width = 0.4mm, ->, >=stealth'] 
        let \n1 = {int(mod(\x + 1,8))}, 
            \n2 = {int(mod(\x + 2,8))}, 
            \n3 = {int(mod(\x + 4,8))}  
        in
        (\x) edge (\n1) edge (\n2) edge (\n3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But it's not even compiling, and I can't understand why. I'd appreciate any assistance.

Comment: I want them to be numbers, they're the labels of the `node`s created earlier no? If I write `(1)` that refers to `node (1)`, right? Should I have used `\p` instead?

Comment: related (duplicae) to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281031/
%    how-to-draw-a-path-to-form-a-regular-pentagon/281038#281038

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a different method, using `evaluate` instead. Note that I made the loops from 0 to 6, and used `mod(i, 7)`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick, scale=1]
        % Nodes     
        \draw foreach \x in {0,...,6}{
            (51.42*\x + 38.58:2.5) node(\x) {\footnotesize\textsf \x}
        };

        % Edges
        \foreach [evaluate={
              \NA=int(mod(\x + 1,7));
              \NB=int(mod(\x + 2,7));
              \NC=int(mod(\x + 4,7));
              }]
        \x in {0,...,6}{
        \path[line width = 0.4mm, ->, >=stealth'] (\x) edge (\NA) edge (\NB) edge (\NC);
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

When you use `let ... in` syntax, the definition of `\x` is changed because when you use a point declaration `\p1=...` then TikZ automatically defines `\x1` and `\y1`. Hence if you change your loop variable to something else it works. I've added also the node `0` to make it work but I don't know if that's your intention

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, scale=1]
    % Nodes     
    \draw \foreach \x in {0,...,7}{
        (51.42*\x + 38.58:2.5) node[font={\footnotesize\sffamily}](n-\x){\x}
    };
    \pgfnodealias{n-0}{n-7} % Make n-0 point to n-7
    % Edges
    \foreach \zz in{1,...,7}{\draw let \n1 = {int(mod(\zz + 1,8))},
                                       \n2 = {int(mod(\zz + 2,8))},
                                       \n3 = {int(mod(\zz + 4,8))}  in 
    (n-\zz) edge (n-\n1) edge (n-\n2) edge (n-\n3);}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) - a language that's actually designed for drawing, and that you might like to learn as well (or instead).

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}

vardef connect(expr a, b) = 
    drawarrow a--b 
        cutbefore fullcircle scaled 20 shifted a
        cutafter  fullcircle scaled 20 shifted b;
enddef;

beginfig(1);
    % how many points?
    N = 7;
    % define the points, from the top, counter-clockwise
    for i=0 upto N-1:
        z[i] = up scaled 100 rotated (360/N*i);
    endfor
    % connect as desired
    interim ahangle := 30; % with slim arrow heads
    for i=0 upto N-1:
        connect(z[i], z[(i+1) mod N]);
        connect(z[i], z[(i+2) mod N]);
        connect(z[i], z[(i+4) mod N]);
    endfor
    % label all the points...
    for i=0 upto N-1:
        label(decimal (i+1), z[i]) withcolor .67 red;
    endfor
endfig;

\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

This is wrapped up in `luamplib`, so compile with `lualatex` or adapt it for `gmp` package, or plain MP.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative using the graph stuff. Compile with `lualatex`

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,graphs,graphdrawing,graphs.standard}
\def\typeset{\pgfmathparse{int(\tikzgraphnodename-1)}\pgfmathresult}
\begin{document}
\tikz[>=stealth']\graph [radius=2cm, typeset=\typeset, ->] 
  { subgraph K_n [n=7, clockwise]; };
\end{document}
```

[image]