# Trouble using a predefined constant in tikz partway calculations

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a diagram with a bunch of nodes determined using partway calculations. I made a definition using `\def\x{.35}` to store the partway distance (because I want to use the same distance in a bunch of calculations). (In particular, I want to draw some nodes that are equally spaced on the side of a line, but offset, kind of.)

When I try to use the \x value in a calculation (the commented out line below) where I'm also using a let statement (so that I can do modular arithmetic), it gives me the error `Argument of \x has an extra }. Inserted text \par`.

If I replace \x with its value .35 in the \path command, everything compiles. The problematic line is commented out in the MWE below.

(I tried enclosing the \x in braces; no good. I tried putting it in the let statement as `let \n1 = ...,  \n2 = {\x} in ...` and that didn't work either.)

What is it about this command instead of the previous ones that TikZ doesn't like?

A minimal-ish working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\def\z{.1}
\def\x{.35}
\begin{tikzpicture}[vtx/.style={draw, circle, gray, font=\tiny, inner    sep = 1 pt}, flag/.style={draw, circle, font=\tiny, inner sep = 1 pt}, scale = 3]

\node[vtx] (v0) at (0,0){$0$};
\foreach \i in {0, ..., 5}{
\node[vtx] (v1 \i) at (360*\i/6:1){$1_{\i}$};
\path let \n1 = {int(mod(\i+1, 6))} in node[vtx] (v4 \i) at ($(360*\n1/6:1)+(360*\n1/6-30:1)$){$4_{\i}$};
}
\foreach \i in {0, ..., 5}{
\node[flag] (0 \i) at ($(v0)!\x!(v1 \i)!\z!90:(v1 \i)$){};
\node[flag, fill=red] (b \i) at ($(v1 \i)!\x!(v4 \i)!\z!90:(v4 \i)$){};

%\path let  \n1 = {int(mod(\i+1, 6))} in node[flag] (8 \i) at ($(v4 \i)!\x!({v1 \n1})!\z!90:({v1 \n1})$){};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to call the variables `\x` and `\z`. Change them to e.g.  `\XX` and `\ZZ`.

Comment: See this one https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/399278/3235

Comment: Yep, changing the \x to \w fixed the problem, per the previous question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've changed some `calc` commands for `evaluate` options and changed `\n1` to `\ni` in last loop and it worked (no errors, but I don't know if it's the desired result):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\def\z{.1}
\def\x{.35}
\begin{tikzpicture}[vtx/.style={draw, circle, gray, font=\tiny, inner    sep = 1 pt}, flag/.style={draw, circle, font=\tiny, inner sep = 1 pt}, scale = 3]

\node[vtx] (v0) at (0,0){$0$};
%\foreach \i in {0, ..., 5}{
%   \node[vtx] (v1 \i) at (360*\i/6:1){$1_{\i}$};
%   \path let \n1 = {int(mod(\i+1, 6))} in node[vtx] (v4 \i) at ($(360*\n1/6:1)+(360*\n1/6-30:1)$){$4_{\i}$};
%}

\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \angle using 60*\i
            ] in {0, ..., 5}{
    \node[vtx] (v1 \i) at (\angle:1){$1_{\i}$};
    \node[vtx] (v4 \i) at ($(\angle+60:1)+(\angle+30:1)$){$4_{\i}$};
}

\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \ni using {int(mod(\i+1,6))}] in {0,...,5}{
    \node[flag] (0 \i) at ($(v0)!\x!(v1 \i)!\z!90:(v1 \i)$){};
    \node[flag, fill=red] (b \i) at ($(v1 \i)!\x!(v4 \i)!\z!90:(v4 \i)$){};
    \node[flag] (8 \i) at ($(v4 \i)!\x!(v1 \ni)!\z!90:(v1 \ni)$){};
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I do not know if the drawing represents something specific but it's really nice.

Comment: What does evaluate do? It looks really handy. And what's the difference between \n1 and \ni? I thought you had to go in order like \n1, \n2...

Comment: @LeahWrennBerman Look at section about `foreach` In pgfmanual. Evaluate does this, computes some operation and stores into a variable. \ni is a variable, \n1 gave me problems.