# The Tikz Code of a Digraph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, tikz-graphdrawing

I have the following adjacency matrix:

```
$
A=
\left[
\begin {array}{cccccccc} 
1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\ 
0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\ 
0&0&1&1&0&0&0&0\\ 
0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0\\ 
0&0&0&0&1&1&0&0\\ 
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\ 
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1\\ 
1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0
\end {array} 
\right] 
$
```

The digraph that represents this adjacency matrix is:

[image]

I obtained the jpg format of this digraph by Maple software.

Is it possible to ask you to help me to write latex code of this digraph with tikz package. One of the my problems is that how to make a loop over vertexes 1, 3 ,5 and 7.

I appreciate you taking the time to help me.

Comment: Like this ?https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399269/drawing-a-graph-with-a-loop-and-mod-function-in-tikz

Comment: @percusse Thanks for your comment. But in accepted answer of that post  there is no loop vertexes.

Comment: what kind of loop ?

Comment: @percusse when in the adjacency matrix the (i,i)th entry is non-zero then we have a cycle of length 1 which is called loop, over the vertex i.

Comment: Also relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203070/36686

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modifying the code from [How to draw a graph in LaTeX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985507/how-to-draw-a-graph-in-latex), one can obtain this **MWE**:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [nodePath/.style={circle,fill=yellow!40}]
  \node[nodePath] (n1) at (0,4)  {1} edge [loop above] ();
  \node[nodePath] (n2) at (3,3)  {2};
  \node[nodePath] (n3) at (4,0)  {3}  edge [loop right] () ;
  \node[nodePath] (n4) at (3,-3)  {4};
  \node[nodePath] (n5) at (0,-4)  {5}  edge [loop below] ();
  \node[nodePath] (n6) at (-3,-3)  {6};
  \node[nodePath] (n7) at (-4,0)  {7} edge [loop left] ();
  \node[nodePath] (n8) at (-3,3)  {8};

  \foreach  \from/\to in {n1/n2,n2/n3,n3/n4,n4/n5,n5/n6,n6/n7,n7/n8,n8/n1}
    \draw[->] (\from) -- (\to) node [midway, auto] () {1};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This results in:

[image: TikZ image]

### Graph with labelled loops

Adding extra nodes allows adding labels:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [nodePath/.style={circle,fill=yellow!40}]
  \node[nodePath] (n1) at (0,4)  {1} edge [loop above] ();
  \node[nodePath] (n2) at (3,3)  {2};
  \node[nodePath] (n3) at (4,0)  {3}  edge [loop right] () ;
  \node[nodePath] (n4) at (3,-3)  {4};
  \node[nodePath] (n5) at (0,-4)  {5}  edge [loop below] ();
  \node[nodePath] (n6) at (-3,-3)  {6};
  \node[nodePath] (n7) at (-4,0)  {7} edge [loop left] ();
  \node[nodePath] (n8) at (-3,3)  {8};

  \foreach  \from/\to in {n1/n2,n2/n3,n3/n4,n4/n5,n5/n6,n6/n7,n7/n8,n8/n1}
    \draw[->] (\from) -- (\to) node [midway, auto] () {1};

  \node[above of= n1] {1};
  \node[right of= n3] {1};
  \node[below of= n5] {1};
  \node[left of= n7] {1};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which then results in:

[image: Graph with labelles loops]

Comment: Thank you so much for your nice code. Can I ask you why you used \documentclass{standalone} instead of \documentclass{article}. I checked the difference of these two mods are in the size of output of image. Am I right. Thanks again.

Comment: You are right, the `standalone` class produces only a pdf of the minimum required size. You can then use `\includepdf` to include it so that the diagram gets calculated only once (which is time-saving).

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to help me.

Comment: Again +1. Using an octagon, i.e. a 8-sided polygon, which (also) comes with the `shapes.geometric` library, may allow you to shorten the code considerably.

Comment: I want to ask you, if it is possible, please help me about make the number 1 over loop edges. Thanks

Comment: really appreciate for your nice edition.

Answer (score 5):

In this case, the octagon is based on a `regular polygon` node. This way, we obtain named anchors in each vertex which can be used to draw labels on them.

As vertex numbers grow counter clockwise, `xscale=-1` allows to flip them.

Three `foreach` sentences draw labels, arrows and loops.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    nodePath/.style={circle, fill=yellow!40}]

\node[minimum size=8cm, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=8, 
       shape border uses incircle, 
       shape border rotate=22.5, 
       xscale=-1] (p) {};

\foreach \i in {1,...,8}
    \node[nodePath] (p-\i) at (p.corner \i) {\i};

\foreach \i [remember=\i as \j (initially 8)] in {1,...,8}
    \draw[->] (p-\j)--node[auto] {1} (p-\i);

\foreach \i/\j in {1/above,3/right,5/below,7/left}
    \path (p-\i) edge [loop \j] ();
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate for your nice code.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using the `TikZ` `circular` `graphdrawing` library and its `simple necklace` graph drawing algorithm. Compilation of code using the graph drawing libraries requires `lualatex`. The graph is updated to also label the loops. Since all the edges are labeled with `1`, the `tikzset` option includes `edge label=1`, avoiding the need to manually label every edge.

[image]

The code:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz,border=3pt,multi]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{circular}

\tikzset{
   myedges/.style={
    draw=black,
    line width=1pt,
    ->,             % always draw arrow tip
    >=stealth,      % style of arrow tip
    shorten >=2pt,  % shorten a bit, so that it doesn't quite
    shorten <=2pt,  % touch the nodes
    font=\scriptsize,
    edge label=1    
    },
    mynodes/.style={
     node sep=2cm,
     anchor=center,
     text=black,
     inner sep=2pt,
     shape=circle,
     draw=none,
     fill=yellow,
     font=\normalfont,
     minimum height=10pt
   }
}

\begin{document}

\tikz \graph [simple necklace layout,
   nodes=mynodes,
   edge=myedges]
    {  1 -- [loop above]     % loop at 1
       1 -- [orient=-22.5]   % Edge from 1 -> 2 at -22.5 degrees
       2 --                  % Edge from 2 -> 3
       3 -- [loop right]     % Loop at 3
       3 --                  % Edge from 3 -> 4
       4 --                  % Edge from 4 -> 5
       5 -- [loop below]     % Loop at 5
       5 --                  % Edge from 5 -> 6
       6 --                  % Edge from 6 -> 7
       7 -- [loop left]      % Loop at 7
       7 --                  % Edge from 7 -> 9
       8 --                  % Edge from 8 -> 1
       1
    };

\end{document}
```

Comment: I appreciate for your nice code.