# who draw Pentagon graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf

who draw pentagon graph, drawing line only Environment. Ie not inside the line.
Thank you

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mystyle/.style={draw,shape=circle,fill=white}]
\def\ngon{5}
\node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\ngon,minimum size=3cm] (p) {};
\foreach\x in {1,...,\ngon}{\node[mystyle] (p\x) at (p.corner \x){};}
\foreach\x in {1,...,\numexpr\ngon-1\relax}{
  \foreach\y in {\x,...,\ngon}{
    \draw (p\x) -- (p\x);
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your description is rather unclear, but from the image I assume you want to add `draw` to the options of the first `\node`. I.e. `\node [draw,regular polygon,...`.

Comment: @percusse I recognize [your style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281039/9335). Why you ask questions under fake profile ? ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mystyle/.style={draw,shape=circle,fill=white, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4pt, label={[anchor=center, label distance=2mm](90+360/\ngon*(#1-1)):#1}}]
\def\ngon{5}
\node[draw, regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\ngon,minimum size=3cm] (p) {};
\foreach\x in {1,...,\ngon}{
    \node[mystyle=\x] (p\x) at (p.corner \x){};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. How can I decrease the size of a circle? Example 4pt

Comment: Also, how do I place a label for each circle?

Comment: @user152035 Take a look at updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here my code with labels for each circle.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[minimum size=4cm,draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=5] (a) {};
\foreach \i in {1,...,5}
    \node[circle,radius=.1cm,draw,
    label=above:{$\i$},
    fill=white] at (a.corner \i) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```