# draw pentagon graph and labels

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am attempting to generate the following graph. who draw graphs?

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}

\def\r{4pt}
\def\dy{1cm}
\tikzstyle{c}=[draw,circle,fill=black,minimum size=\r,inner sep=0pt, anchor=center]
\tikzstyle{d}=[draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=\r,inner sep=0pt, anchor=center]

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Ncorners}{5}
\node[draw, regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\Ncorners,minimum size=2.5cm] 
(poly\Ncorners) {};
\foreach\x in {1,...,\Ncorners}{
    \node[d,label=left:$x$] (poly\Ncorners-1\x) at (poly\Ncorners.corner \x){};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Check out this thread: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281031/how-to-draw-a-path-to-form-a-regular-pentagon

Comment: thanks, It has large circles and also no labels.

Comment: Unrelated comment: I would recommend you use `\newcommand` instead of `\def`, as `\def` will just overwrite existing macros without telling you. In this particular case, `\r` is an existing macro, used for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(diacritic), so your `\def\r` will for example destroy any occurrences of the letter `å` in a document. Not saying you have any of those, but as a general point, you might end up redefining some important macro and break your document if you're not careful. I suggest `\newcommand\rad{4pt}` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}

\def\r{4pt}
\def\dy{1cm}
\tikzset{c/.style={draw,circle,fill=black,minimum size=\r,inner sep=0pt,
anchor=center},
d/.style={draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=\r,inner sep=0pt, anchor=center}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Ncorners}{5}
\node[draw, regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\Ncorners,minimum size=3cm] 
(poly\Ncorners) {};
\node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\Ncorners,minimum size=3.5cm] 
(outerpoly\Ncorners) {};
\foreach\x in {1,...,\Ncorners}{
    \node[d] (poly\Ncorners-\x) at (poly\Ncorners.corner \x){};
    \node (outerpoly\Ncorners-\x) at (outerpoly\Ncorners.corner \x){$x_\x$};
}

\foreach\X in {1,...,\Ncorners}{
\foreach\Y in {1,...,\Ncorners}{
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Z}{abs(mod(abs(\Ncorners+\X-\Y),\Ncorners)-2)}
\ifnum\Z=0
\draw (poly\Ncorners-\X) -- (poly\Ncorners-\Y);
\fi
}
}
\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Ncorners}{7}
\node[draw, regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\Ncorners,minimum size=3cm] 
(poly\Ncorners) {};
\node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\Ncorners,minimum size=3.5cm] 
(outerpoly\Ncorners) {};
\foreach\x in {1,...,\Ncorners}{
    \node[d] (poly\Ncorners-\x) at (poly\Ncorners.corner \x){};
    \node (outerpoly\Ncorners-\x) at (outerpoly\Ncorners.corner \x){$x_\x$};
}

\foreach\X in {1,...,\Ncorners}{
\foreach\Y in {1,...,\Ncorners}{
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Z}{abs(mod(abs(\Ncorners+\X-\Y),\Ncorners)-2)}
\ifnum\Z=0
\draw (poly\Ncorners-\X) -- (poly\Ncorners-\Y);
\fi
}
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDITIONAL REQUEST**: Clockwise labelling.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}

\def\r{4pt}
\def\dy{1cm}
\tikzset{c/.style={draw,circle,fill=black,minimum size=\r,inner sep=0pt,
anchor=center},
d/.style={draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=\r,inner sep=0pt, anchor=center}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]
\begin{scope}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Ncorners}{5}
\node[draw, regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\Ncorners,minimum size=3cm] 
(poly\Ncorners) {};
\node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\Ncorners,minimum size=3.5cm] 
(outerpoly\Ncorners) {};
\foreach\x in {1,...,\Ncorners}{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\y}{90-(\x-1)*360/\Ncorners}
    \node[d] (poly\Ncorners-\x) at (\y:1.5){};
    \node (outerpoly\Ncorners-\x) at (\y:1.75){$x_\x$};
}

\foreach\X in {1,...,\Ncorners}{
\foreach\Y in {1,...,\Ncorners}{
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Z}{abs(mod(abs(\Ncorners+\X-\Y),\Ncorners)-2)}
\ifnum\Z=0
\draw (poly\Ncorners-\X) -- (poly\Ncorners-\Y);
\fi
}
}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Ncorners}{7}
\node[draw, regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\Ncorners,minimum size=3cm] 
(poly\Ncorners) {};
\node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\Ncorners,minimum size=3.5cm] 
(outerpoly\Ncorners) {};
\foreach\x in {1,...,\Ncorners}{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\y}{90-(\x-1)*360/\Ncorners}
    \node[d] (poly\Ncorners-\x) at (\y:1.5){};
    \node (outerpoly\Ncorners-\x) at (\y:1.75){$x_\x$};
}
\foreach\X in {1,...,\Ncorners}{
\foreach\Y in {1,...,\Ncorners}{
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Z}{abs(mod(abs(\Ncorners+\X-\Y),\Ncorners)-2)}
\ifnum\Z=0
\draw (poly\Ncorners-\X) -- (poly\Ncorners-\Y);
\fi
}
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. Sorry i did not particularity.

Comment: @user152035 BTW, I cannot read the indices of your screenshot, but it is straightforward to put whatever instead of `\X`.

Comment: You can avoid all calculations in the double loop by simply not drawing the pentagon node initially, and then do `\foreach[count=\maxY]\X in {2,...,\Ncorners} \foreach\Y in {1,...,\maxY} \draw (poly\Ncorners-\X) -- (poly\Ncorners-\Y);`.    As a bonus : if you change `\Ncorners` it still works ;)

Comment: @Kpym Why is that simpler and what do you mean by "it also works"? This loop just checks if the current node and another node differ by 2 units, and then draws the connection. This also works for arbitrary N (except of course you need to replace "5" by "\Ncorners").

Comment: It is simpler because you have nothing to check ;) And no it is not working if your replace `5` by  `\Ncorners` ... check it for `\Ncorners=7`.

Comment: @Kpym Sorry, it *is* working. I just added the `\Ncorners=7` case.

Comment: This is not a complete 7-graph. But may be you are right, may be this is what is needed, but I don't know what is this family of graphs. Particular kind of 4-regular graphs ?

Comment: @Kpym I agree that for higher N it is not clear what the generalization will be,

Comment: @marmot Sorry, can the labels be from right to left

Comment: @user152035 But still starting from the top?

Comment: @marmot Yes, but go straight ahead.

Comment: @user152035 I am sorry, I do not understand your request. Can you please tell me if your just want to exchange `x_2` with `x_5` and `x_3` with `x_4` or something else. Please be precise.