# how draw graph in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

> Based on [draw pentagon graph and labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431015) by [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot) (Edit [Manuel Kuehner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14649))

I want to be drawn diagonally from all nodes in the same way as an image.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}

\def\r{4pt}
\def\dy{1cm}
\tikzset{c/.style={draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=\r,inner sep=0pt,
anchor=center},
d/.style={draw,circle,fill=black,minimum size=\r,inner sep=0pt, anchor=center}}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Ncorners}{5}
\node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\Ncorners,minimum size=2cm] 
(poly\Ncorners) {};
\node[draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\Ncorners,minimum size=4cm] 
(outerpoly\Ncorners) {};
\foreach\x in {1,...,\Ncorners}{
    \node[d] (poly\Ncorners-\x) at (poly\Ncorners.corner \x){};
    \node[d] (outerpoly\Ncorners-\x) at (outerpoly\Ncorners.corner \x){};
    \draw (poly\Ncorners-\x) -- (outerpoly\Ncorners-\x);
}

\foreach\X in {1,...,\Ncorners}{
\foreach\Y in {1,...,\Ncorners}{
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Z}{abs(mod(abs(\Ncorners+\X-\Y),\Ncorners)-2)}
\ifnum\Z=0
\draw (poly\Ncorners-\X) -- (poly\Ncorners-\Y);
\fi
}
}
\node at (0,-2) {$G^2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Example figure:
[image]

Comment: It is good habit to cite [your sources](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/431019).

Comment: Thanks, Yes it is. But this seems to me different. Because in addition to the lines drawn, a line must be drawn from all external nodes to the inner nodes as well as to other nodes.

Comment: Someone has voted to close your question as "unclear what you are asking". While I voted not to close the question for now, I at least partially agree that the question is a bit unclear. Do you want to only draw the additional lines/curves or do you want more? Is it always the same node, or do you want that to be customisable?

Comment: For the moment, I have the same shape and I want to have all the nodes together. And, for example, the edge from the upper node to the bottom is connected to the curve, so that it does not pass through the middle node. If it's not understandable, it's more for non-English speaking than being a servant.

Comment: @Kpym I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also not sure if I understand what you are asking. So perhaps it is the simplest thing if I post something that might be it and you tell me what else should be done.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}

\def\r{4pt}
\def\dy{1cm}
\tikzset{c/.style={draw,circle,fill=white,minimum size=\r,inner sep=0pt,
anchor=center},
d/.style={draw,circle,fill=black,minimum size=\r,inner sep=0pt, anchor=center}}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Ncorners}{5}
\node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\Ncorners,minimum size=2cm] 
(poly\Ncorners) {};
\node[draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\Ncorners,minimum size=4cm] 
(outerpoly\Ncorners) {};
\foreach\x in {1,...,\Ncorners}{
    \node[d] (poly\Ncorners-\x) at (poly\Ncorners.corner \x){};
    \node[d] (outerpoly\Ncorners-\x) at (outerpoly\Ncorners.corner \x){};
    \draw (poly\Ncorners-\x) -- (outerpoly\Ncorners-\x);
}

\foreach\X in {1,...,\Ncorners}{
\foreach\Y in {1,...,\Ncorners}{
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Z}{abs(mod(abs(\Ncorners+\X-\Y),\Ncorners)-2)}
\ifnum\Z=0
\draw (poly\Ncorners-\X) to (poly\Ncorners-\Y);
\draw (outerpoly\Ncorners-\X) to[bend left=15] (poly\Ncorners-\Y);
\draw (outerpoly\Ncorners-\X) to[bend left=30] (outerpoly\Ncorners-\Y);
\fi
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Z}{abs(mod(abs(\Ncorners+\X-\Y),\Ncorners)-1)}
\ifnum\Z=0
\draw (outerpoly\Ncorners-\X) to[bend left=15] (poly\Ncorners-\Y);
\fi
}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think that the question was simply how to draw something like `\draw (outerpoly5-1) to[bend left=15] (poly5-5);`.

Comment: @Kpym Merci. But I am not sure, there is an "all" in "I want to be drawn diagonally from all nodes in the same way as an image.". The simplest option would be if the OP told us.