# TikZ: convenient way to draw Metcalfe's law network diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf

Metcalfe's law is a simple principle that says a network with n nodes has n(n-1)/2 possible undirected connections between nodes. It is often illustrated thus (wikipedia):

[image: Metcalfe's law diagram]

Is there an easy way to replicate this in TikZ. Ideal would be an approach that allows the user to specify the number, n, of nodes and then draws n nodes symmetrically positioned around a circle with all of the possible n(n-1)/2 connections between them.

Comment: Are you aware of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281031/121799)?

Comment: @marmot I wasn't but it's perfect, thanks! This should probably be marked as a duplicate.